# In HSQLDB can you SELECT into a variable and use that in an INSERT

Tags: sql, variables, select, hsqldb, declare

I'm using an in memory HSQLDB for integration testing.

Currently we have various test SQL files  with many INSERT statements such as

```
insert into customer(id, name, email) values (99, 'John Doe', 'john@test.com');

...

insert into order(id, owner, itemref, quantity) values(1, 99,  'abc', 1);
insert into order(id, owner, itemref, quantity) values(2, 99,  'def', 1);
insert into order(id, owner, itemref, quantity) values(3, 99,  'ghi', 1);
```

Is it possible to do a SELECT into a variable and subsequently use that in an INSERT?

e.g. something like:

```
declare custid bigint;
custid = select id from customer where email = 'john@test.com';

insert into order(id, owner, itemref, quantity) values(1, @custid,  'abc', 1);
insert into order(id, owner, itemref, quantity) values(2, @custid,  'def', 1);
insert into order(id, owner, itemref, quantity) values(3, @custid,  'ghi', 1);
```

I've tried looking at the HSQLDB docs but all the info about 'variables' is regarding procedures, rather than simple INSERTS etc.

Comment: ps I think I've done something similar in mysql before...

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for what you're trying to achieve using the HSQLDB SqlTool is:

`* VARIABLE ~
SQL QUERY RETURNING THE VALUE TO ASSIGN;`

Which then lets you use its value further down the script with:

`SOME OTHER SQL QUERY WHERE *{VARNAME};`

Therefore this is how your code above could be written:

```
* custid ~
select id from customer where email = 'john@test.com';

insert into order(id, owner, itemref, quantity) values(1, *{custid},  'abc', 1);
insert into order(id, owner, itemref, quantity) values(2, *{custid},  'def', 1);
insert into order(id, owner, itemref, quantity) values(3, *{custid},  'ghi', 1);
```

Reference: [HSQLDB SqlTool - PL User Variables](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/util-guide/sqltool-chapt.html#sqltool_variables-sect)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as :

```
insert into order(id, owner, itemref, quantity) 
values(1, (select id from customer where email = 'john@test.com'),  'abc', 1);
```

Comment: Thanks but thats not what I was looking for, Im ok with subqueries

Answer (score 0):

Well if the INSERT statements are for test data, you can write a simple PROCEDURE containing those statements. You can then define a session varaiable with this and call the procedure:

```
DECLARE myvar VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'JOHN@SOMETHING';

CALL myproc(myvar);
```

The session variables can be arrays and you can use loops in the procedure to insert multiple rows with the array elements.